# PostgreSQL operator doesnt exist for array of floating numbers

Tags: arrays, postgresql

My column definition is `array2 double precision[] NOT NULL`.

I have 2 queries.

```
select *
from test
where ARRAY[1.1, 2.2, 3.3] <@ array2;
```

and

```
select *
from test
where '{1.1, 2.2, 3.3}' <@ array2;
```

Second one works fine, but first gives me `ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric[] <@ double precision[]`.

Casting for type helps, but why it doesn't work without it?

```
select *
from test
where ARRAY[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]::double precision[] <@ array2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax with `array`, in contrary to the other, allows the parser to immediately resolve the type of the expression:

```
select '{1.2}', pg_typeof('{1.2}'), array[1.2], pg_typeof(array[1.2])

 ?column? | pg_typeof | array | pg_typeof 
----------+-----------+-------+-----------
 {1.2}    | unknown   | {1.2} | numeric[]
(1 row)
```

The type of `'{1.2}'` is `unknown` and it is resolved in a later phase when the operator is applied. The type of the right-hand operand fits, so `unknown` is successfully resolved to `double prcission[]`.